# AngularJS How to pass the searchtext to filter a table in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

Using AngularJS. I have a couple of search fields for a table. The table is used in various locations with different data so I made it a directive. The search fields are outside of the directive. I can't figure out how to pass the searchText from the main page to the table in the directive. I've tried different approaches from the things I've found online, but below is the basic details of the table and it displays just fine. The search also worked fine before I broke the table out into a directive. I just can't figure out how to apply the filter from outside the directive.

The html:

```
    <label>Search: 
        <input class="" ng-model="searchText.commodityId" placeholder="Commodity Code">
        <input class="" ng-model="searchText.commodityName" placeholder="Commodity Name">
    </label>

    <fiveyearreporttable location="location" 
      year="year" 
      rows="fiveYearCargoReport.allMajorGroup" 
      searchText="searchText"></fiveyearreporttable>
```

The directive:

```
    angular.module('webPubsApp')
      .directive('fiveyearreporttable', function () {
        return {
          templateUrl: 'views/templates/inc-five-year-report-table.html',
          restrict: 'E',
          scope: {
              location: '=',
              year: '=',
              rows: '=',
              searchText: '='
          }
        };
      });
```

The relevant html from the templateUrl:

```
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rows| filter:searchText " ng-class-even="'even-row'">
```

Comment: `search-text="searchText"`

Comment: It didn't work with the hyphen, but I changed it to all lower case and it worked like a champ! Thanks much!